# How to calculate weighted ranking instead of sorting by in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a database structure like this (tables):

**products**

```
id
title
```

**product_ratings**

```
id
product_id
score
ip_address
```

so imagine we need to sort products by ratings.

ordering by the average rating is not good enough, this means that an article with only one score of 5 would outrank articles with multiple 4 score ratings.

what can I do for this issue?

Comment: Something like, sort by _number_ or ratings first then, and only by the actual average value second?

Comment: This is not a programming question then, you need to come up with the business logic for calculating product ratings. There are quite a few ways to do it.